NextJS | How to stop bundling css in NextJS 13 or 14
I am running a server side rendereded Next 13 app. I am having issue related to Largest Contentful paint which is getting affected because the bundled css files are loading at the highest priority and causing render blocking issue. Is there any way to de prioritize the css or stop adding it from the server rendered html?
